# Rest Api load tesing Zerocode tdd giving error message

Tags: java, junit5, rest-assured, zerocode

I'm automating my rest api and searching for a performance testing framework to use with my junit5. I came across zerocode tdd but it is not helping it's giving error and all the tests are falling under failure. My test method is proper and works when it invoked normally by junit jupiter. When I use zerocodeLoadRunner for the same thing it is not working.

```
    import org.jsmart.zerocode.core.domain.LoadWith;
    import org.jsmart.zerocode.core.domain.TestMapping;
    import org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.parallel.ZeroCodeLoadRunner;   
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    @LoadWith("loadConfig.properties")

    @TestMapping(testClass = MyTest.class, testMethod = "myMethod")

    @RunWith(ZeroCodeLoadRunner.class)

    public class LoadTest  {

    }
```

The error message I am getting is as follows.

```
    2019-09-09 12:35:57,191 [main] ERROR org.jsmart.zerocode.core.runner.parallel.ZeroCodeLoadRunner - myPackage.LoadTest.myMethod Failed. See target/logs -or- junit granular failure report(csv) -or- fuzzy search and filter report(html) for details
```

The dependency used for this is as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsmart</groupId>
        <artifactId>zerocode-tdd-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't want to use any testing tool so I'm going with this.

Comment: You can check out https://gatling.io/, it's open source but quite large and powerfull.

Comment: LoadRunner or [jMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org)  whereas JMeter is freeware LoadRunner is a commercial tool

Comment: I don't want to use any tool. I want to include it in my test suite.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You might have better luck getting an answer on here if you stick to 1 question at a time - I would suggest you update your question to only ask about help with zerocode tdd, as asking for recommendations of tools is out of scope for questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The setup which you have done works for `JUnit4`(but not for JUnit5 as JUnit5 does not support `Runners`). For **JUnit5**, you need to use the following extention of zerocode.

> `@ExtendWith({ParallelLoadExtension.class})`

This [JUnit5-Jupiter-Parallel-Load-Extension](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/JUnit5-Jupiter-Parallel-Load-Extension#existing-junit5-tests) page has the precise details. Please try the below way:

e.g.

```java
@LoadWith("load_generation.properties")
@ExtendWith({ParallelLoadExtension.class})
public class JUnit5LoadCommonLoadTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testing parallel load for X, Y and Z scenarios")
    @TestMappings({
            @TestMapping(testClass = JUnit5Test.class, testMethod = "testX"),
            @TestMapping(testClass = JUnit5Test.class, testMethod = "testY"),
            @TestMapping(testClass = JUnit5MoreTest.class, testMethod = "testZ")
    })
    public void testLoad_xyz() {
        // This space remains empty
    }
}
```

You can visit this [Github JUnit5 Load examples](https://github.com/authorjapps/performance-tests/tree/master/src/test/java/org/jsmart/zerocode/samplesjunit5/loadjupiter) for `JUnit5 Jupiter` load tests and also how to run them via `JUnit5 Suite`.

Comment: Is there any way to randomize the order of the test mappings methods?

Comment: @Jas, In the `load_generation.properties`, set `ramp.up.period.in.seconds=0` to randomize the order.

Comment: @Jas, not that I have seen at this point. You may be able to use Junits `@Order` annotation in your original test file if you need specific order.

Answer (score 0):

I second the answer above the issue is you are setup using JUnit4 style tests and need to setup for JUnit5 - I have tested this as recently as the last few weeks and works exactly as specified above.

One item to note is that in the properties file I have found you need to set seconds 15-20% higher than threads (ie threads 20 / seconds 25). If you do not then I very commonly see failures in the zerocode test