# How do i repeatedly run a junit5 test class for long period of time, in random order, with multiple instnaces?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, docker-swarm, junit5

I have a piece of hardware that I would like to hit with tests for several days. Interfacing through the device is done through a java library (.jar). I'd like to use junit5 to write tests and hit that library (and thus the device). There are some conditions which we are trying to create: 1) The tests should be in random order and 2) There should be some level of concurrency for the tests.

Here is what I was thinking:

I create a test class called `MyTestClass` that has some fixed test methods. I can set the test method order as follows: `@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.Random.class)`

The part that I'm not sure how to do next is to spin up `x` instances of `MyTestClass` that will execute in parallel, and allow me to say run each instance for `y` number of hours.

If there are alternative methods in junit5 that I can use to accomplish my goals, I'm all ears.

EDIT:
I haven't worked out all of the details yet, but i believe I'm going to go ahead and package my test class in a docker container. Then bring up a swarm of containers. I probably need to figure out how to aggregate the reporting.

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure this is something you do not need to control fully yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i was hoping to leverage some of the functionality of junit5

Comment: I'm not sure if this is something you would want to use junit for, sounds to me like you want some sort of login mechanism coming from the device.

Comment: You could take the device out of the equation. I'm essentially testing a java application, a .jar.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with a custom [test runner](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-4-custom-runners). Eg

```
@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)
@MyTestRunnerContext(
   runTimeSeconds=86_400, 
   threadCount=10, 
   order=Order.RANDOM
)
public class MyTest {
   @Test public void test1() {...} 
   @Test public void test2() {...} 
}
```

Comment: that seems to be deprecated in juni5. It's been replaced with `ExtendWith` but i'm not sure if i could do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This [JUnit5 Load Extension](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/JUnit5-Jupiter-Parallel-Load-Extension) might help. To randomize the order, visit this SOF [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849469/rest-api-load-tesing-zerocode-tdd-giving-error-message).